# Time Complexity of printing a list

Tags: python, list, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Here are 2 different codes performing the same function that is printing a list.

- code-1

```
list1=[5,4,86,2,4,5,3,4]
for i in list1:
    print(i,end=" ")
```

- code-2

```
list1=[5,4,86,2,4,5,3,4]
print(list1)
```

Can I say that printing a list has a time complexity of O(n)? While calculating the time complexity of any program we don't consider the time complexity of printing statements as it takes order of 1 but as in the `code-1` it takes order of n.

I am an introvert in Python. So if possible please also share the backend implementation of `print(list)` or else if any article or blog on it.

Comment: How are they the same functions? One loops through the elements in the list, the other prints the list object

Comment: same functions in the sense gives same out put

Comment: That's not what 'introvert' means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output is different, but that's not important.

Either method is *O(n)*.

In the first case each element of the list is visited once hence *O(n)*.

In the second case the `print()` function itself iterates over the list visiting each element once, also *O(n)*.

If you really want to you can read the code in the [Python source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bcb094b41f7fe4dd1686c50891d85632fcf0d481/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1829) repository.